# How to get a long type in PHP

Tags: php, curl, long-integer

when i request a third-part api by curl,the param must be long.But there is no long type in PHP. How can I let the int transport to long?you can see picture.
should I use GMP?

I am using php 5.6.27.

[image]

Comment: Just use a string

Comment: The name "room ID" suggests is isn't a number at all, it's just a string identifier that happens to contain only numbers. You should verify whether the API actually cares. What payload format does it expect? JSON? XML?

Comment: ad your code as code not as a picture

Comment: Sorry,guys, it's my mistake. it is ask a long type,but I just make my param become a json,so it dosen't pass. Thanks everyone, and Álvaro González ,you remind me the json part,THANK YOU. It is my first time using stackoverflow,never using picture again